# How do we prove that :$\tan^2(10)+\tan^2(50)+\tan^2(70) =9$

Tags: trigonometry, summation

**Question**

> Prove : $\tan^2(10) + \tan^2(50) 
> + \tan^2(70) =9$

**my attempt**

Let  $\text{t} :=\tan(10)$

$$\tan^2(10) + \tan^2(50) 
+ \tan^2(70) = \tan^2(10) + \tan^2(60-10) 
+ \tan^2(60+10)=t^2 + \left({\frac{\sqrt{3}-t}{1+\sqrt{3}t}}\right)^2+\left({\frac{\sqrt{3}+t}{1-\sqrt{3}t}}\right)^2=\frac{9t^6+45t^2+6}{(1-3t^2)^2}$$

and therfore :

$$\tan^2(10) + \tan^2(50) 
+ \tan^2(70) =\frac{9\tan^6(10)+45\tan^2(10)+6}{(1-3\tan^2(10))^2}$$

**I need help completing the proof or give another way and I appreciate everyone's interest**

Comment: Just to clarify, are you working with radians or degrees?

Comment: Working  be degrees

Comment: You may want to see if you can adapt any of the proofs given here: [Evaluate $\tan^{2}(20^{\circ}) + \tan^{2}(40^{\circ}) + \tan^{2}(80^{\circ})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175736). It includes an answer that gives the general expression $\sum_{l=1}^n\tan^2\left(\frac{\pi l}{2n+1}\right)=n(2n+1)$ (in radians), with a proof given in a link, but that uses a complex analysis method. There are posts with your exact question but they aren't quite... I don't know, clear? For example: [Proving $\tan^210^\circ+\tan^250^\circ+\tan^270^\circ=9$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1198248)

Comment: Note that $\tan{(90-x)}=\cot{x}$. Perhaps now you can adapt the answer linked by @BrunoB ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your notation, we have
$$
\tan(20)=\frac{2\tan(10)}{1-\tan^2(10)}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2} \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\tan(30)=\frac{\tan(20)+\tan(10)}{1-\tan(20)\tan(10)}=\frac{\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+t}{1-\frac{2t^2}{1-t^2}}=\frac{3t-t^3}{1-3t^2}. \tag{2}
$$
Squaring $(2)$ and simplifying, we obtain
$$
\frac{t^6-6t^4+9t^2}{1-6t^2+9t^4}=\tan^2(30)=\frac{1}{3}\implies t^6=9t^4-11t^2+\frac{1}{3}. \tag{3}
$$
We can now use $(3)$ to rewrite the RHS of your last equation as
$$
\frac{9\left(9t^4-11t^2+\frac{1}{3}\right)+45t^2+6}{(1-3t^2)^2}=
\frac{9(9t^4-6t^2+1)}{(1-3t^2)^2}=9, \tag{4}
$$
hence
$$
\tan^2(10)+\tan^2(50)+\tan^2(70)=9.\quad{\square} \tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $\;t=20^{\LARGE\circ},\; u=\cot t,\;v=\cot 2t,\;w=\cot 4 t,\quad $ then
$$S =\tan^2 10^{\LARGE\circ}+\tan^2 50^{\LARGE\circ}+\tan^2 70^{\LARGE\circ}=\cot^2 80^{\LARGE\circ}+\cot^2 40^{\LARGE\circ}+\cot^2 20^{\LARGE\circ}=u^2+v^2+w^2,$$
$$\cot8t=\cot 160^{\LARGE\circ}=-u.$$

From the known identity
$$\cot(2a)=\dfrac12(\cot(a)-\tan(a))=\dfrac{\cot^2(a)-1}{2\cot(a)}\tag1$$
should
$$u^2=2uv+1,\quad v^2=2vw+1,\quad w^2=-2wu+1,\tag2$$
where
$$u>v>w>0.\tag 3$$
Summation of the equalities $(2)$ allows to get
$$(u-v+w)^2=u^2+v^2+w^2-2v(u+w)+2uw=3,$$
$$u-v+w=\sqrt3.\tag4$$
Then
$$v=\dfrac{u^2-1}{2u},\tag5$$
$$w=\sqrt3+v-u=\sqrt3+\dfrac{u^2-1}{2u}-u,$$
$$w=\sqrt3-\dfrac{u^2+1}{2u}.\tag6$$

On the other hand,
$$\dfrac1{\sqrt3}=\cot 3t=\dfrac{u(u^2-3)}{3u^2-1},$$
$$u^3=\dfrac{3u^2-1}{\sqrt3}+3u\tag7.$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
&u^2+v^2+w^2=u^2+\left(\dfrac{u^2-1}{2u}\right)^2+\left(\sqrt3-\dfrac{u^2+1}{2u}\right)^2\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac1{4u^2}\left(4u^4+\left(u^2-1\right)^2+\left(2u\sqrt3-u^2-1\right)^2\right)\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac1{4u^2}\left(6u^4-4u^3\sqrt3+12u^2-4u\sqrt3+2\right)\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac1{4u^2}\left(6u^4-4u^3\sqrt3+12u^2-4u\sqrt3+2
-(6u+2\sqrt3)\left(u^3-\dfrac{3u^2-1}{\sqrt3}-3u\right)\right)\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac{36u^2}{4u^2}=9.
\end{align}$$