# Evaluate $\cos 10^{\circ}+\cot 23^{\circ}-\sin 12^{\circ} + cos 12^{\circ}$

Tags: general-topology

Evaluate

$$\cos 10^{\circ}+\cot 23^{\circ}-\sin 12^{\circ} + cos 12^{\circ}$$

Can you help me please!

Comment: @coffeemath it does actually equal 36

Comment: @5201314 My bad. was using secant. Erasing comment.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175736/evaluate-tan220-circ-tan240-circ-tan280-circ

Comment: @Liza Please don't retroactively erase your question after it already has an accepted answer.  I've rolled it back to what seems to be the most recent valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the identity $4\cos^3t-3\cos t=\cos 3t$, verify that $\cos20$, $-\cos40$ and $-\cos80$ are the three roots of
$$4x^3-3x=\frac12 $$
Square to get $64x^6-96x^4+36x^2-1=0$, or the cubic equation for $\frac1{x^2}$

$$\frac1{x^6}-\frac{36}{x^4} +\frac{96}{x^2} -64=0$$

Thus
$$
\csc^2 10+\csc^2 50+\csc^2 70= \frac1{\cos^280}+ \frac1{\cos^240}+ \frac1{\cos^220}=36
$$