# Necessary condition for positive-semidefiniteness -- is it sufficient?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that I have a symmetric square $n\times n$ matrix $A$ such that:

> $a_{ii}\geq 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, and that $a_{ii}a_{jj} - a_{ij}^2 \geq 0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ and $i < j \leq n$.

Clearly this is a necessary condition for positive semidefiniteness because of Sylvester's criterion, and the fact that $P^TAP$ is positive semidefinite for any positive semidefinite $A$ and permutation matrix $P$.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168717/about-positive-semidefiniteness-of-one-matrix) hints that this condition is not sufficient. Can you list any simple counterexamples to the claim that this condition is sufficient for $A$ to be positive semidefinite? Thanks.

P.S. I won't be offended if you flag this as a duplicate, but it's the counterexamples I'm interested in, so please consider that before you flag.

Comment: So for example (referencing the previous question) you'd be interested in an example that satisfies the above condition but doesn't have a Cholesky decomposition ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat That would be a good example, yes.

Comment: John, I put a third answer generalizing things. I had to do it. The voices made me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for being slow. There is a good reason this did not occur to me first, but still an error of sorts. Take

$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
1 &  -1  &  -1  \\
-1 &  1  &  -1  \\
-1 & -1 & 1
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$

Your conditions are fulfilled but it is evident that $-1$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector
$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{r}
1   \\
1   \\
1 
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$

To get strict inequalities use some $0 < \delta < 1$ and the matrix

$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{ccc}
1 + \delta &  -1  &  -1  \\
-1 &  1 + \delta &  -1  \\
-1 & -1 & 1 + \delta
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$ 
which keeps that eigenvector but now the eigenvalue is $\delta -1.$

Answer (score 4):

I won't need to show a matrix this time. For a square $n$ by $n$ matrix with $n \geq 3,$ let $M$ be the symmetric matrix with all off-diagonal entries equal to $-1$ and all diagonal entries equal to $n-2.$ It is not difficult to show, using the eigenvalues, that all the principal minors up to size $n-1$ are nonnegative, so those submatrices are positive semidefinite. However, once again we get an eigenvalue of $-1$ with the eigenvector made up of all $1$'s. To get the submatrices positive definite, make the diagonal entries $n-2+ \delta$ with $0 < \delta < 1.$

Lost my nerve:
$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrr}
2 &  -1  &  -1 &  -1    \\
-1 &  2  &  -1 &  -1    \\
-1 &  -1  &  2 &  -1    \\
-1 &  -1  &  -1 &  2    
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$ 
and
$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrrrr}
3 &  -1  &  -1 &  -1  &  -1  \\
-1 &  3  &  -1 &  -1  &  -1  \\
-1 &  -1  &  3 &  -1  &  -1  \\
-1 &  -1  &  -1 &  3  &  -1  \\
-1 &  -1  &  -1 &  -1  &  3  
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$

Anyway, a $k$ by $k$ matrix consisting of all $1$'s has eigenvalues $0,0,0,\ldots, 0,k.$ If all the entries are $-1$ instead the eigenvalues are $0,0,0,\ldots, 0,-k.$ In order to put some number $w$ on the diagonal we need to add $(1 + w)I,$ where $I$ is the identity matrix. So the eigenvalues of the $k$ by $k$ matrix with all off-diagonal entries $-1$ and all diagonal entries $w$ are  $1+w, \; 1+w, \; 1+w,\ldots, \; 1+w, \; 1 + w-k.$ This is how you quickly confirm the example above.

Answer (score 3):

$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
1 &  -2  &  -3  \\
-2 &  4  &  -6  \\
-3 & -6 & 9
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$

determinant is $-144.$

If you want strict inequalities, 
$$ 
 \left(  \begin{array}{rrr}
1001 &  -2000  &  -3000  \\
-2000 &  4001  &  -6000  \\
-3000 & -6000 & 9001
\end{array} 
  \right)  
$$

This determinant is  $-143999985999.$

Comment: This is a great example because all of the 2x2 submatrices are p.s.d., but the matrix isn't (edit: actually I just realized that that's exactly what I asked for). May I ask how you thought of this example?

Comment: @JohnMoeller, I mostly do integral quadratic forms in three variables. So I just programmed my calculator to do the determinant. Putting squares on the diagonal allowed your conditions, but when I had positive elements off-diagonal the determinant was $0.$ Then I realized that if I negated all off-diagonal entries, I would be subtracting off a strictly positive quantity and that would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$A=\pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 2 & 4 \cr 1 & 4 & 9}$$
Then *all* $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ minors are positive, not just the principal ones, but the determinant is still negative, so $A$ cannot be positive semidefinite.

This is related to [total positivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_positive_matrix); the matrix $A$ is totally positive of order two, but not of order three.