# If $A=(a_{ij})$ is positive semidefinite, prove that $a_{ij}^2 \leq a_{ii}a_{jj}$ for all $i \neq j$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A=(a_{ij})$ is positive semidefinite, prove that $a_{ij}^2 \leq a_{ii}a_{jj}$ for all $i \neq j$.
I don't even know how to get started, any hint is appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: see related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235170/necessary-condition-for-positive-semidefiniteness-is-it-sufficient/235224#235224

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: By Cauchy-Schwarz you have $(x^tAy)^2 \le (x^tAx)(y^t Ay)$ for any $x,y \in \mathbb R^d$.

You can of course try to mimic the proof of Cauchy-Schwarz and start with 
$$ 0 \le (e_i + se_j)^tA(e_i + se_j) = a_{ii} + 2sa_{ij} + s^2a_{jj} $$
Now let $s = -\frac{a_{ij}}{a_{jj}}$. You of course have to consider the case $a_{jj} = 0$ seperately.

Comment: Is there any alternative approach that does not require the use of this inequality?

Comment: @drawar Why do you not want to use Cauchy-Schwartz?

Comment: Actually I'm practicing for my exam and Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is not covered in my course so I'm not supposed to use it.

Comment: @user1551: My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need $(x^tAx)\geq0$ for all $x$ and $x$. Now if you set $x=e_i+te_j$, you get a quadratic polynomial in $t$ which must be non-negative for all $t$. So this polynomial cannot have any non-repeated roots, as polynomials must be positive on one side of these and negative on the other.

So the discriminant of this polynomial (i.e. $b^2-4ac$ if your polynomial is $at^2+bt+c$) must be non-positive - when you work out what the coefficients are in terms of the matrix entries, this will be the inequality you want.

Comment: The discriminant must be non-positive.

Comment: @Jack Indeed - thanks!

Comment: Your first line should be You need $(x^t A x) \geq 0$ for all $x.$

Comment: @WillJagy Also true, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, since it has not been mentioned:

A matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite if and only if every principal submatrix of $A$ is positive semidefinite.  Thus, if $A$ is positive definite, then every principal submatrix must have a non-negative determinant.

Note that
$$
\pmatrix{
a_{ii}&a_{ij}\\
a_{ji}&a_{jj}
}
$$
is a principal submatrix of $A$, so its determinant must be non-negative.  Note that since $A$ is positive semidefinite, it is symmetric so that $a_{ji} = a_{ij}$.  The conclusion follows.